# postgresql drop table

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables (tbl and tbl_new) that both use the same sequence (tbl_id_seq).  I'd like to drop one of those tables.  On tbl, I've removed the modifier "not null default nextval('tbl_id_seq'::regclass)" but that modifier remains on tbl_new.  I'm getting the following error:

ERROR:  cannot drop table tbl because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  default for table tbl_new column id depends on sequence tbl_id_seq

After reviewing http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-droptable.html
It looks like there is only CASCADE and RESTRICT as options.

Comment: how did you create the tbl_id_seq? and how do you drop tbl? Please provide some code. (I just tested it and it worked fine for me so most likely the problem is in a detail thats not provided here.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [decouple](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) the sequence and the table it "belongs" to:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "tbl_id_seq" OWNED BY NONE;
```

I suppose it was created [automatically](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (and "bound") by defining the `tbl_id` field of `tbl` as `SERIAL`.

Answer (score 2):

To **find sequences** and all **tables that depend** on them via column default:

```
SELECT sn.nspname || '.' || s.relname AS seq
      ,tn.nspname || '.' || t.relname AS tbl
FROM   pg_class s
JOIN   pg_namespace sn ON sn.oid = s.relnamespace
LEFT   JOIN pg_depend d ON d.refobjid = s.oid AND d.deptype <> 'i'
LEFT   JOIN pg_attrdef ad ON ad.oid = d.objid
LEFT   JOIN pg_class t ON t.oid = ad.adrelid
LEFT   JOIN pg_namespace tn ON tn.oid = t.relnamespace
WHERE  s.relkind = 'S'
AND    s.relname ~~ '%part_of_seq_name%' -- enter search term here
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Now with `LEFT JOIN` to show "free-standing" sequences as well.
You can then use the method @Milen posted to make the sequence "free-standing".

I posted a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8270947/939860) a few days ago.