# How to delete unused/large number of sequences from postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my `vb.net` application's back-end using is `PostgreSQL`.application uses temporary tables to do some works(since am a `DBA` i dont know what they are doing). today i saw something wrong in the `DB`.Basically `DB` 's number of `sequences` is `70`, but in one `DB` i saw (see the below image)

[image]

- this `DB` has some problems like slowness,unexpected server shut down

So give some suggestions to delete these sequences from `DB`

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265540/how-to-delete-unused-sequences.

Use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270947/1283020

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for this

*create a query to find out the `sequences` to drop*

> SELECT 'drop sequence ' || c.relname || ';' FROM pg_class c WHERE
>   (c.relkind = 'S') and (c.relname not ilike  '%gtab%' and c.relname not ilike  '%gcom%')

- this will return all the unsed(in my case) `sequences`

[image]

*Using copy command exported the results to .CSV*

- > copy( SELECT 'drop sequence ' || c.relname || ';' FROM pg_class c
  >   WHERE (c.relkind = 'S') and (c.relname not ilike  '%gtab%' and
  >   c.relname not ilike  '%gcom%')) to 'D:/DelSeq.csv' with csv header
- myCsv File
  [image]
- I have copied the entire results from .csv and executed it as `pgScript`

**DONE**